# knockout.js with checkbox checked bind when checked ,will trigger the update method in custom binging why

Tags: knockout.js

```
var viewModel={
   isChecked:ko.observable(false);
   showMessage:ko.observable();
};

ko.bindingHandlers.doSomeing=function(){
   update:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext){

      if(viewModel.isChecked){

       }

   }
};

<pre>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:isChecked"></input>

<input type="text" data-bind="doSomeing:showMessage"></input>
</pre>
```

when clicked the checkbox will trigger the update method in custom binging doSomeing,why?

but remove if(viewModel.isChecked) scope , will not trigger update method .

Comment: html for this would be usefull. even better if you can make a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` method in a KO binding is executed within a computed observable.  So, any observables that have their value accessed (like `viewModel.isChecked()` in your case, just doing `viewModel.isChecked` would not access the value, so you might have a typo in your question), will become a dependency and cause the binding's update function to run again.

Just a note: All bindings on an element are actually run within a single computed, so all bindings on that element will run their update functions again whenever any dependency changes. These dependencies are tracked each time, so they can change over time.  In Knockout 3.0, bindings will be run independently of each other on a single element.

Comment: how can i use viewModel.isChecked in update method,when click checkbox but will not tigger update method.because I must do some conditions for viewMdel.isChecked property